# Prove or disprove:If $m^*(E)+m^*([0,1]-E)=1 $ then $E$ is a measurable set.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

Prove or disprove the following statement.

> Let $E\subset [0,1]$, if $ m^*(E)+m^*([0,1]\setminus E)=1$ ,then $E$ is a measurable set, where $m^*$ is Lebesgue outer measure.

At first glance, I thought it is triavially true.

That is, the set $E$ is measurable provided for **any** set $A$, $$m^*(A \cap E)+m^*(A\cap E^c)=m^*(A)..............(*),$$

and thus

$$m^*(E)+m^*([0,1]\setminus E) =  m^*([0,1]\cap E)+m^*([0,1]\setminus E)=m([0,1])=1.$$

Hence $E$ is measurable. But I realized that using the whole set $[0,1]$ as $A$, i.e., $A=[0,1]$ is just a particular case and that I need to show  that $(*)$ is true for any set $ A$.

Can someone give me an idea how to go by this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any set $A$; $m^*(A)+m_*([0,1]\setminus A)=1$

Also it is given that $m^*(A)+m^*([0,1]\setminus A)=1$

Hence we have $m^*([0,1]\setminus A)=m_*([0,1]\setminus A)\implies [0,1]\setminus A $
is measurable $\implies A$ is measurable

Comment: That is nice, I had actually not thought of inner measure so I was seeking to do it with outer measure but this is also correct as far as I can see.
Thank you.

Comment: Do accept it if this helps you